# Check who has given permission to a user in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom, pnp-powershell, powershell-script

In sharepoint line for a site I have a few site owners. One owner has stopped inheriting permissions for a library and a folder and gave access to a user. As a tenant admin I want to know who that owner has provided access and breaked the permissions . Is there any powershell script or csom to know it.

Answer (score 1):

Changes to permissions can be audited using [Audit Log Reports](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527). You will need to enable Auditing to view these reports.

In Microsoft 365, you can also use the [Security and Compliance Center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?view=o365-worldwide) to view audit logs from across multiple applications including SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cmdlet `Search-UnifiedAuditLog` to search the unified audit log, which requires the [Exchange Online PowerShell V2 module](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps) to work.

See the sample script via this link: [SharePoint Online: How to View Audit Log Reports in Security & Compliance Center?](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/09/sharepoint-online-search-audit-logs-in-security-compliance-center.html)

You can find the available Operations on Site permissions activities [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?view=o365-worldwide#site-permissions-activities).